# JFrame On Close Operation

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, windowlistener

I was wondering if there is a way, by clicking on the "X", to let the program perform some code before closing the JFrame. The `setDefaultCloseOperation()` method takes only an integer.

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might be interested in using a [`WindowListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html). The [`WindowListener` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html).

Comment: Thank you, very much. Thats just what im after.

Comment: Or you can use [WindowAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html) as convenience for creating listener objects.

Answer (score 23):

```
this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                    int i=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Seguro que quiere salir?");
                    if(i==0)
                        System.exit(0);//cierra aplicacion
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 16):

@Jeffrey has a good answer, but you should consider what you're trying to do. If you really want to do something upon the closing of a frame, then a WindowListener is the way to go. However, if you're looking for a place to do some cleanup and graceful shutdown stuff, then you probably want a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) instead. Using a WindowListener, the code will only be triggered, as you said, by the user "clicking on the X". But what if the user starts the app in the foreground of a terminal and kills it with Ctrl+C? What if the user kills the process from the command line or from a task manager?

Comment: Wow, thank you for you reply. Im using this to save some data upon closing the frame.

Comment: @Sanjay: I chose to link jdk6 because 1) in my experience, more people are still using 6 than 7, and 2) Runtime.addShutdownHook() didn't change a lick between 6 and 7.

Comment: okay,point taken :) but I usually prefer to link to the latest docs whatsoever !