# Do something before window closes after user presses [x]

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener

I'm building an instant messenger application.I need to add an action event on the default closing button of the Swing JFrame(The little "x").
When the client presses the X button,I need to tell the server that he goes offline and only after that action occures I have to close the window.I can't seem to find how to get an action listener on the default button.

Comment: This type of question has only been asked over a hundred times here including: [JFrame On Close Operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468149/jframe-on-close-operation). Voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Close it, newbie mistake.Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take a look of this may its helps you. [Closing an Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/)
You can give your own implementation if some one press close button.

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

frame.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter()
 {
   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
    {
      // Here you can give your own implementation according to you.
     }
  });
```

Comment: I was close.I just wrote new windowAdapter without adding it.Didn't realize.Thanks man!

Answer (score 5):

Look into the Runtime.addShutdownHook() method. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29

Answer (score 4):

Simply [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#addWindowListener%28java.awt.event.WindowListener%29) a [WindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) to your JFrame and use the event [windowClosing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosing%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to call [`addWindowListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#addWindowListener%28java.awt.event.WindowListener%29) with a `WindowListener` which handles [`windowClosing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosing%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) or [`windowClosed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosed%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29). You may well want to create a subclass of [`WindowAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html) so you can just override the method(s) you're interested in.

Don't forget that your communication with the server should be in a different thread - don't block the UI thread with network traffic. However, also bear in mind that if your whole application is closing:

- Any connection to the server will close anyway
- Any *background* threads will be terminated

Answer (score 3):

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("Blah");
f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        //do whatever you want before the window closes.
    }
});
f.setVisible(true);
```

Don't do `f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` because that might interrupt your server communications. Instead, say `System.exit(0)` manually when you have done your server communications.